# C# Reference any version?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to not reference a specific but instead reference any version with C#? Or am I stuck setting up a PostBuild script that strips the specific version?

The reference is to another project in the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can assembly bindingRedirect help you somehow?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are talking about assembly versions, In Visual Studio you can right click an assembly reference, click "Properties", and change "Specific Version" to "false".

Comment: Forgot to mention it is a project in the same solution so that option is missing.

Comment: I think at that point you are better off using a solution using assembly redirection, as Marino Šimić suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a version of an assembly, then yes.

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Stand on reference, look in property window (F4 to jump there), find "Specific Version" and change it to false.
2. Open up the .csproj file of the assembly that references the other assemly with a text or xml editor, search file for the name of the referenced assembly and remove the version number from the file.